# How to append the FormArray of one component with the values of another component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use the same FormArray between two components to save the data. Both the component code looks like this:

xyz.component.ts

```
createForm(data: any): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    contractId: [data ? data.contractId : ''],
    contractName: [data ? data.contractName : '', Validators.required],
    contractServiceList: this.formBuilder.array(
      this.createContractService(data ? data.contractServiceList : null), this.arrayValidator()
    )
  });
}

createContractService(data: any[] | null): FormGroup[] {
  return data ?
    data.map(x => {
      let group = this.formBuilder.group({
        serviceId: [x.serviceId, Validators.required],
        copay: [x.copay, Validators.required],
        coinsurance: [x.coinsurance, Validators.required],
        deductibleApplies: [x.deductibleApplies, Validators.required],
        penaltyApplies: [x.penaltyApplies, Validators.required],
      });
      return group;
    }) : [this.formBuilder.group({
      serviceId: ['', Validators.required],
      copay: ['', Validators.required],
      coinsurance: ['', Validators.required],
      deductibleApplies: ['', Validators.required],
      penaltyApplies: ['', Validators.required],
    })];
}
```

abc.component.ts

```
createForm(data: any): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    contractId: [data ? data.contractId : ''],
    contractName: [data ? data.contractName : ''],
    contractServiceList: this.formBuilder.array(
      this.createContractService(data ? data.contractServiceList : null), this.arrayValidator()
    )
  });
}

createContractService(data: any[] | null): FormGroup[] {
  return data ?
    data.map(x => {
      let group = this.formBuilder.group({
        penaltyRule: [x.penaltyRule, Validators.required],
        penaltyType: [x.penaltyType, Validators.required],
        penaltyValue: [x.penaltyValue, Validators.required],
        deductibleAppliesPenalty: [x.deductibleAppliesPenalty, Validators.required]
      });
      return group;
    }) : [this.formBuilder.group({
      penaltyRule: ['', Validators.required],
      penaltyType: ['', Validators.required],
      penaltyValue: ['', Validators.required],
      deductibleAppliesPenalty: ['', Validators.required]
    })];
}
```

Onclick of Save button, it navigates to next component so the FormArray should get appended with the values in second as well after saving the values from first.

Comment: You could do a `form.patchValue` but the field names aren't the same. Would you consider making them the same?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: No, it's like there are 4 fields in 1st and 3 fields in 2nd so finally when I hit Save button of second component, I should get all 7 fields into same createContractService[].

Comment: I'd recommend you create a StackBlitz in that case. It would be easier to be looked into.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: You can refer the code here - cost-share and penalty folders. https://angular-vdg7rq.stackblitz.io

Comment: This StackBlitz lacks your implementation. Please add that and share it across. Also add it to the question once done.

Comment: Getting error while creating blitz - ERROR
Error: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function, Is the obove code not clear enough for the solution I want? Please ask for the clarification, I'll give

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180148/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-meenal).